# Using CSS to Draw 3 Vertical Lines on an Image

Tags: html, css

So I'm really new using CSS, I need to add 3 vertical red lines on top of an image, the lines have to split the image in 4 equally sized parts. The size of the image is always 465*346 and the mark up I have so far looks like this

**CSS:**

```
.logo-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 87px;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 144px;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 72px;
    height: 87px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.logo-line {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="preview-image-wrapper">
   <span class="firstOverlayLine" ></span>
   <span class="secondOverlayLine"></span>
   <span class="thirdOverlayLine"></span>
   <img id="mainImage" type="image" class="mainimage" data-bind="attr: {src: SelectedImagePath}" />
</div>
```

The above is my attempt to modify [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AFBCC/2/) example to make it fit my needs, but with no success so far.

The end result should look like:

[image: Every part divided should be the same size]

Comment: Could you add an image of what it should look like?  I'm having trouble imagining the end result.

Comment: Do you need to use an img element, or you'd be happy to have it as a background-image on preview-image-wrapper div instead?

Comment: Done, they are not equal on the sample, but the idea is to have all 4 parts be roughly the same size

Comment: @robjez I need to keep the img tag

Comment: My answer has been updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something raw like this - floating 1px-wide spans over the image, keeping your original HTML:

```css
div {
  width: 465px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 346px;
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
}

.firstOverlayLine {
  left: 25%;
}

.secondOverlayLine {
  left: 50%;
}

.thirdOverlayLine {
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview-image-wrapper">
   <span class="firstOverlayLine"></span>
   <span class="secondOverlayLine"></span>
   <span class="thirdOverlayLine"></span>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/465x346">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great.... just another quick question, after implementing this I realized that all images had a kind of a header on them of about 15px so I now want the red line to not go all the way to the top of the image but about 15px from the top, so I tried adding a css rule of Top:15px but it does it from the top of the page instead of the div... any idea how to properly do this>

Comment: You can try `margin-top: 15px`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements.

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  width: 465px;
  height: 346px;
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/465x346/ddd5ed/fff);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#img:before, #img:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#img:after {
  left: 75%;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
```

Comment: Still 2 lines - you'll have trouble making 3 lines with pseudo-elements.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - it need to be split into 4 equal parts

Comment: just make the width to 25% and left to 50%

Comment: @ankitchaudhary And the third one?

Comment: Downvote for stealing @web-tiki's code, just changing the colors.

Comment: @shomz whats the third one? It will divide it into 4 equal parts...as shown by web-tiki

Comment: @ankitchaudhary web-tiki showed his example much later... at that time we have 2 lines...

Comment: easy guys, anyone can use "my code" I'm just trying to help :)

Comment: @web-tiki - I didn't though. You can look at the code, its totally different.

Comment: @Shomz....this what i was talking about [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbrEbN)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using unordered list:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4q63mwc/

```
<div id="preview-image-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/465x346" />
</div>   


div, img {
  width: 465px;
  height: 346px;
  position: relative;
}

ul { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 346px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:200;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li { 
    height:346px; 
    border-right:1px solid red; 
    width:25%; 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a horizontal line, if someone needs it.

```css
div {
  width: 465px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 465px;
  background: red;
}

.firstOverlayLine {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview-image-wrapper">
   <span class="firstOverlayLine"></span>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/465x346">
</div>
```