# Lines with spaces on img element

Tags: html, css

```css
img:after,
img:before {
  /*POSSIBLE SOLUTION WITH PSEUDO?*/
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
```

I have to draw two vertical lines on the left side of an `img` element. The lines should have a `width` of `5px`. The first line is on the left side of the img. Than there comes a space of another `5px` until the second line starts.

I'v found this solution with `span` elements: [Using CSS to Draw 3 Vertical Lines on and Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488495/using-css-to-draw-3-vertical-lines-on-and-image)

Is there an bether alternative solution? I tried it with pseudo `:after` and  `:before` but didnt' get it. Any ideas?

**Original image:**
[image]

**Image with lines:**
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are having with the way you are currently doing it? Also, please include your HTML and CSS that you are currently using for this, so we can help.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it other way than spans or divs over original image.

Comment: Have you tried to use `::before` / `::after` pseudo-elements of the image's parent/wrapper?

Comment: Show us your markup, don't be shy :)

Comment: @tilz0R You can also with CSS gradients, with pseudo-elements.

Comment: `pseudo-elements` would work, but only if you apply them to a containing element, wrapped around the `img` tag - the `img` tag is a self-closing void tag, so it cannot have any `pseudo-elements` applied to it, since it cannot *contain* any elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with \`img\` elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the image and put the pseudo elements on the wrap. Try like so:

```css
.my-image-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.my-image-wrap:before,
.my-image-wrap:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.my-image-wrap:after {
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-image-wrap">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the image a background element, then add a border and a pseudo element:

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey url("http://www.lorempixel.com/600/300");
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below demonstrates how you can achieve the intended result using `pseudo-elements` applied to a containing parent element.

```css
.img-wrapper:before,.img-wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 5px;
    background: red;
    height: 99%;
}

.img-wrapper:before {
    left: 0;
}

.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper:after {
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga"></div>
```